# Write truncate only a specific partition in date partitioned table in BigQuery Schedule job

Tags: google-bigquery

Using the Bigquery Schedule functionality, is it possible to write truncate a partition using the run_time parameters like `@run_time`?

What I am trying to do is to give the destination table_name like `mytable${run_time|"%Y%m%d"}`, but this gives me an error saying:

```
Invalid partition decorator in column-partitioned table mytable$20200124 with partitioning field { value: "event_date" }
```

If I don't give the partition decorate the whole table is written truncated irrespective of the partition

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I just replicated it with the following configuration [image: Scheduled query configuration]

Notice that the Partitioning field is empty. In addition, I found this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/127700807) where is provided the following workaround:

> [...] If you just want to overwrite on partition, you could use [MERGE statement on the query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) and set the "Destination table" to the column-partitioned table.